# How to use the Vibrator in an Android Library Module

Tags: java, android

My goal is to make a simple library with some basic vibration methods so that I can have a more diverse and native set of options in some other frameworks. My problem is that I cannot use `getActivity()` or `getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVER)` inside the library.

Here is the library class I have so far:

```
import android.os.Vibrator;
public class Vibration {

private Vibrator _vibrator;

     public static void Vibrate(long milliseconds ){
         Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
         //getActivity().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
         v.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(
            milliseconds,VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
     }
}
```

I am getting `Cannot resolve symbol 'Context'`, and the same for `getSystemService`

Anyone have an idea of to call these methods from the library?

Comment: you need to ``import android.content.Context``...

Comment: This helped but I need a way to get the current context still. @Rutvik's answer works if you have another context, but because this is a library I don't think I will actually have another Context to pass in.

Answer (score 2):

you need to pass context object in Vibrate() method as below:

```
public static void Vibrate(long milliseconds, Context context) {
    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    v.vibrate(VibrationEffect.createOneShot(
            milliseconds, VibrationEffect.DEFAULT_AMPLITUDE));
}
```

and for Context you need to import`import android.content.Context;`

Comment: This works if you have another context, but because this is a library I don't think I will actually have another Context to pass in. Is there a way that I can use a system call or something like that get the current context?

Comment: Recommend making Context the first parameter to be consistent with SDK API's

Comment: If this is library you can get Application context as user's of your library initialize in Application class